# Panoramio - Will I be able to use 'get_panoramas.php' after November 4th 2016?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, panoramio

I saw the [deprecation message](http://www.panoramio.com/maps-faq) and the [blog post by Google](https://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.co.il/2014/06/sunsetting-javascript-api-weather-panoramio.html) and I'm completely stumped on what will continue to work and what not.

I don't upload images to my account. I understand that this service will no longer be available.

What I do use, is this api: http://www.panoramio.com/map/get_panoramas.php, for showing images near locations on my website.

Will I be able to keep using it?

If so, until when? And shouldn't that be clearly stated?

If not, is there a parallel Google Maps api to get such images? I'm aware of Google Locations api, but I'm more interested in nearby outdoors images, and not places of business and named land marks.

Thank you.

**UPDATE:** as stated in the comment, the service is indeed down. The image urls we already have are still operational for another year, but we can't search for other existing images anymore. So we made the transition to Flickr. It was very easy and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

It is stated in the [link](http://www.panoramio.com/maps-faq) that you provide that **after November 4, 2016, you’ll continue to have access to your photos in Panoramio for a year, but take note that you will no longer be able to add new photos, likes, or comments**.

I suggest you to check this [Google Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro), it lets you embed a Google Maps image on your web page without requiring JavaScript or any dynamic page loading. The Google Static Maps API service creates your map based on URL parameters sent through a standard HTTP request and returns the map as an image you can display on your web page.

Comment: The link says nothing - good or bad - about what will happen to the api. I understand the images will be available on the site for another year, but I'm not sure whether the api will be available or not.

Regarding Google Maps - that's not the correct service. I don't want to display a map in my site. I want to display geo-tagged images from specific locations.

Comment: I think the API will still be available because they continue to let us users to access our photos. But I think the documentation and support on it will not be updated.

Comment: Well, you seem to be wrong and november 4th have arrived and get_panoramas.php is no longer available (404). So anyone knows if there's a matching api in google maps?